# assert function in python

Tags: python, assert

For a given code:

```
pattern = r'(?:some_pattern)'  
def find(seq):
    ret = []
    while True :
        m= pattern_re.match(seq)
        if not m :
            break
        myseq= m.group(2)
        assert len(myseq)%3 == 0
        assert len(myseq) > 6
        ret.append(myseq)
        pos = m.end()
        return ret

sequence = 'some sequence'
my_seq = find(sequence)
```

this returns ret in which only first assert function is taken and not the second . Any solution for it ?

the question simply is how to make code consider both the assert function

Comment: This is not a valid Python program. Please fix your indentation.

Comment: fix the code and describe your problem.

Comment: I can't make heads nor tails of this question. Also, could you make sure that the code you post is syntactically and semantically valid.

Comment: still invalid code, `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Answer (score 2):

For starters, why are you using assert?

As soon as the first assert fails an `AssertionError` is raised and execution of the program stops.

You should be using normal conditionals. Besides that, there is so much wrong with or unusualy with this code I seriously suggest you to read the Python tutorial at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Pointers:

- print statement after return
- usage of assert instead of conditionals
- the unnecessary while loop
- no proper indenting

Furthermore you pasted an example that plainly does not execute since the indenting is wrong and the function called on the last line does not exist in your code. Please be more precise if you want help :-)